# Text is deleted when double-click the input box in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, delete, text-editor

Text is deleted when I double-click it in a text editor or in an input box, which is annoying to me.

For example, if I double-click just after '20.04' when editing the title of this question, '04', '.', '20', 'Ubuntu' ... will be deleted respectively. What's more, if I click 3 times in a row, the whole title will disappear.

[image]

Same things happen when I edit my code in Jupyter Notebook.
How to solve this problem in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Please give step-by-step instructions to reproduce the "problem".

Comment: This sounds like a custom mouse action to cut text into the clipboard. If you [Ctrl]+[V] (or right-click + paste), does the text come back? If so, you'll need to edit your mouse actions with Gnome Tweak.

Comment: I installed Fcitx and Google input and it's OK now.

Comment: @FedKad FYI this indeed a "problem" - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138159

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too. I also found that some games failed to recognise any character keys (i.e. ctrl, alt, shift, numbers, etc all fine, but WASD failed).

In my case, the issue was with my keyboard, `ibus-pinyin`

I found it was reported a long time ago (8 years!): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138159

Solution: Use a different Chinese keyboard. Suggested alternatives:

`ibus-sunpinyin`

`ibus-googlepinyin`

`ibus-libpinyin` <--- I chose this one

(Perhaps you aren't using Chinese keyboard, but I still believe it's a keyboard issue, specially if you're using ibus)